# Mongodb How to Update many documents using C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Please be  so kind to help.

I got List of documents from xml parsing service and trying update it in DB.

I  create  fiter builder like .

```
var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.In("Id", List<T>);
```

and update builder like.

```
var update = Builders<T>.Update.Set("T.Property", List<T> )
```

and using UpdateManyAsync() updating documents  in DB, but changings  not apply.

How  I could  update documents in 1 step ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello this is a sample using a .NET core 3.1 console application.

This is the `csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.13.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

This is the code inside of the `Program.cs` file:

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MongoUpdateMany
{
  public static class Program
  {
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
      const string databaseName = "test";
      const string collectionName = "students";

      var client = new MongoClient();
      var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
      var collection = database.GetCollection<Student>(collectionName);

      // just to be sure the test data are clean, nothing to do with the update sample
      await database.DropCollectionAsync(collectionName).ConfigureAwait(false);

      // create a bunch of students
      var id = 1;

      var enrico = new Student()
      {
        Name = "Enrico",
        Id = id++,
        IsActive = false
      };
      var luca = new Student
      {
        Name = "Luca",
        Id = id++,
        IsActive = false
      };
      var giulia = new Student
      {
        Name = "Giulia",
        Id = id++,
        IsActive = true
      };

      // fill the collection
      await collection.InsertManyAsync(new List<Student> { enrico, giulia, luca }).ConfigureAwait(false);

      // update many
      var ids = new List<int> { enrico.Id, luca.Id };

      var filter = Builders<Student>
        .Filter
        .In(x => x.Id, ids);

      var update = Builders<Student>
        .Update
        .Set(x => x.IsActive, true);

      await collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update).ConfigureAwait(false);

      // verify updating the docs worked
      await collection
        .Find(student => ids.Contains(student.Id))
        .ForEachAsync(student => Console.WriteLine($"Name: {student.Name} IsActive: {student.IsActive}"))
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

  public class Student
  {
    [BsonId]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Here is some useful links to learn how to use the official C# driver for mongodb:

- [driver documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/)
- [free course from the Mongo university](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M220N/about). **I highly encourage you to take this course**: courses available in the Mongo university catalog are of very high quality.

Comment: Tahank you for your answer as I nnderstand  I can't use list of  object in filter and must create id's list ?
And mainly my problem  to update  each document  by different  value, not  1 value  for all documnts.

Comment: @Nevega you need to create a list of whichever data type you are using for the id of your documents. In my example I have used integers, but that's not mandatory. If you use a string property as the object id, then you'll have a list of strings. If, instead, you use a field having the ObjectId data type as the document id, then you'll have to define a list of ObjectIds.

Comment: @Nevega notice also that the UpdateMany operator is meant to apply the same update operation on all the documents matched by the filter document used as a parameter for the UpdataMany itself. So, if in your case you don't want to apply the same update operation to all the matched documents, then UpdatyMany is not the right tool for you. Probably in your case you should use UpdateOne instead and update one document at a time